# Doing semi complicated math with MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am not sure how to import code to look like a table into stackoverflow so I will import 2 photos below instead.

These are screenshots of my tables that I need to use in the query. I would like to compare the competition "experts_coordinates" with the users coordinate_x and _y to see who is the closest and thus the winner.

I don't know exactly how to write this in SQL but this was my idea:

```
//Loop through all the results and do as follow

$user_xy = coordinate_x + coordinate_y;
$expert_xy = explode(',', 'experts_coordinates');
$winning_coords = $expert_xy[0] + $expert_xy[1];
$results = $user_xy - $winning_coords;

//Loop again too see who was the closest too '0'.
//Winner will be the users closest too 0.
```

Something like this?

> NOTE! This is intended to run server side once a week.

[image: Users table with coordinates]

[image: Competition table with winning coordinates]

PS: The php tag is because I used some php code examples to try and demonstrate my idea.

Comment: To `import code to look like tables` - open a cmd prompt. Type `mysql - u root -p databasename` - once logged in enter a query ( terminated by semi-colon ) and hit enter. Then select all output and right click to copy ( this is on windows ) - obviously change root to the actual user and databasename to the name of the db

Comment: Do you want it to be a stored procedure that will run once a week? If so what should it return (User coordinates)?

Answer (score 0):

To find the closest node with xy-coordinates, it might be useful to use euclidian distance:

```
function euclidDistanceSquared (a, b) {
  return (a[0]-b[0])*(a[0]-b[0]) + (a[1]-b[1])*(a[1]-b[1]);
}

$user_xy = array(coordinate_x, coordinate_y);
$expert_xy = explode(',', 'experts_coordinates');
$dsquared = euclidDistanceSquared($user_xy, $expert_xy);

//find smallest dsquared using a loop
```

Comment: I cannot give you more code because you are not providing enough information about your code.

Comment: No you misunderstood. I dont want to do it in code. I want to make an sql query. SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = something + something. The code was only an example to try and paint my trail of thought

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood, but I am presenting the same basic idea in PHP which you need for MySQL. Check out Thorsten Kettner's answer, which uses SQL and the same formula.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL we don't think in loops, but in sets. Read all records and order them by closeness to the desired coordinates. As to the math: that's Pythagoras, right? Well, apply whichever formula you like.

```
select 
  mytable.*,
  sqrt(pow(abs(mytable.coordinate_x - desired.x), 2) + 
       pow(abs(mytable.coordinate_y - desired.y), 2)) as distance
from mytable
cross join 
(
  select 
    cast(substring_index(experts_coordinates, ',', 1) as unsigned) as x,
    cast(substring_index(experts_coordinates, ',', -1) as unsigned) as y
  from experts_table
  where id = 1
) desired
order by pow(abs(mytable.coordinate_x - desired.x), 2) + 
         pow(abs(mytable.coordinate_y - desired.y), 2)
```

Comment: Hi, your answer looks like it will be what I'm looking for but i have a question or two while i figure it out. What is desired? is that the expert coords? How do i break it up into 2 different ones if that is the case?

Comment: I select the one experts record from the second table you've shown and call this "desired". I also split the experts_coordinates into x and y as you can see. Is this what you are referring to with "How do i break it up into 2"?